# Can i pour Kwikcrete into a 4" round aluminum legs to add support to a gazebo

Tags: concrete

Can I pour Kwikcrete into the legs of a gazebo for extra strength? 6' x 4" round. How much should I use?  Other suggestions?

Comment: Possibly one of the "post setting foam" products, or even just canned spray polyurethane foam could work without corroding the aluminum, though the manufacturers declaim any structural value, and the post-setting types react so fast that handling them to pour multiple post interiors might be difficult.

Comment: Is it the legs themselves that need strengthening or their connection at the top of the gazebo?

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. A picture of the gazebo and a description of the problem you're trying to solve, plus any additional info that would help people help you would be good. Just [edit] them into your question.

Comment: I think it's more likely you would weaken the structure due to extra weight of the legs.

Answer (score 7):

[Concrete and aluminum](https://www.dot.ny.gov/divisions/engineering/structures/repository/events-news/2016_LBC_session_4-1.pdf) have an antagonistic relationship, so this would be a ***phenomenally bad*** idea. You'll weaken the aluminum and the concrete.

From the linked document:

> Fresh concrete corrodes aluminum with subsequent release of hydrogen. After the chemical reaction, the concrete loses its properties and deteriorates. The concrete is no longer homogenous.

Comment: interesting point! Could OP line them, say with 6mil plastic?

Comment: spray leftover acrylic spray paint into legs first to form a plastic coat over the metal.

Comment: I suspect it would be diffcult to get complete coverage inside a 6 foot long 4" diameter tube with paint, and likewise difficult to get sheet plastic in place and pour concrete, but if you can manage those without gaps, tears, or pinholes, I guess it could work.